# Two Array for create a table with label id

Tags: php, label

I have two arrays the first represent a keys, the second represent a values

I want to create a table with label tag. 
Each label have an ID.
The keys of Array_keys represent the ID of labels.

```
Array_keys
(
    [71] => firstName
    [51] => LastName
    [20] => Adresse
    [30] => CP
    [40] => tel

)

Array_Values
(
    [0] => AP1W3242
    [1] => AP7X1234
    [2] => AS1234
    [3] => MH9Z2324
    [4] => MX1234

)

/*This is an example for the first row:
 <tr>
    <td> <label id="ID_71"> firstName </label> </td>

    <td> AP1W3242 </td>
  </tr>

*/
```

Comment: Do you mean an HTML table or a database table? You have explained your problem badly and it appears you haven't actually tried anything yet. Welcome to Stack Overflow, but you need to put more effort in if you want help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array_combine($Array_keys,$Array_Values)
```

Comment: array_combine($Array_keys,$Array_Values) ,remove the keys of the tow arrays

Comment: I need an HTML table

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
$Arraykeys=array('71'=> 'firstName','51' => 'LastName','20' => 'Adresse','30'=> 'CP','40'=> 'tel');

$ArrayValues=array('0'=>'AP1W3242', '1' => 'AP7X1234','2' =>'AS1234', '3' => 'MH9Z2324', '4' => 'MX1234');

$Arraykeys1_key=array_keys($Arraykeys);
$Arraykeys1_Values=array_values($Arraykeys);

$ArrayValues_keys=array_keys($ArrayValues);
$ArrayValues_values=array_values($ArrayValues);
$nbrow=sizeof($Arraykeys1_key);

for ($i=0; $i <$nbrow ; $i++) { 
//add code to create the elements of html table.... 
    echo($Arraykeys1_key[$i]);
    echo($Arraykeys1_Values[$i]);
    echo($ArrayValues_keys[$i]);
    echo($ArrayValues_values[$i]);
}

}
```